# How can I bypass Ezproxy with HttpClient?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm creating a script to access university's resource page to fetch some data.
But university redirects me to login page via EZproxy.

When I looked at header even though EZProxy redirects to login page, http status code is 200. Not 30x.

So how can I fetch final URL's (login page) html with HttpClient.